# Can't login in login form even though the credentials is right. I am using Laravel 9

Tags: authentication

This is the code related to a login action. If a user's email and password are validated, it sends them to the dashboard. but even the credentials is right I get an error "login failed". I am using Laravel 9.

web.php

```php
    Route::controller(UserController::class)->group(function(){
        Route::post('/process', 'process');
    });
```

login.blade.php - this is the login view

```html
    
    <form action="/process" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="row">
                      @error('usrEmail')
                          <p class="text-danger text-xs p-1">
                              {{$message}}
                          </p>
                      @enderror
                      <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-4">
                        <label for="usrEmail"></label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg"  placeholder="Email" id="usrEmail" name="usrEmail" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="usrPassword"></label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" id="usrPassword" name="usrPassword" />
                      </div>
    
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="d-flex my-2 justify-content-between">
                          <div class="d-inline-block mr-3">
                            <label for="remember" class="control control-checkbox">Remember me
                              <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember"/>
                              <div class="control-indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                          </div>
    
                          <p><a href="/forgotPassword" class="text-blue">Forgot Your Password?</a></p>
                        </div>
    
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mb-4">Log In</button>
    
                        {{-- <p>Don't have an account yet ?
                          <a class="text-blue" href="sign-up.html">Sign Up</a>
                        </p> --}}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

UserController.php

```php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Models\User;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
    use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
    use Exception;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    
    class UserController extends Controller
    {
       public function process(Request $request) {
           $validated = $request->validate([
               "usrEmail" => ['required', 'email'],
               'usrPassword' => 'required',
           ]);
           if(auth()->attempt($validated)){
               $request->session()->regenerate();
               return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Welcome!');
           }
           else{
               return back()->withErrors(['usrEmail' => 'Login failed!'])->onlyInput('usrEmail');
           }
       }  
    }
```

This is the code related to a login action. If a user's email and password are validated, it sends them to the dashboard. If not, it redirects back to the login page with an error message.